# Invalid ENTRYPOINT when deploying Docker image inside Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I´m getting this error when I run '**gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml**' from gcloud-cli.

```
Step #1: Deploying...
Step #1: Setting IAM Policy.....................................done
Step #1: Creating Revision.....................................................failed
Step #1: Deployment failed
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Invalid argument error. Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "gcr.io/customerapi-275705/quickstart-image@sha256:0d1965181fa4c2811c3fcbd63d68de5b4c348ee5b62615594946dea48fee9735"
Step #1: error: "Command \"/quickstart.sh\": invalid mode \"-rw-rw-rw-\" for /quickstart.sh"
Step #1: ].
Finished Step #1
```

The file is supposed to have '+x' (read/execute) permissions set by chmod. The Windows equivalent would be '*/grant User:F*'.

***Step #1: error: "Command \"/quickstart.sh\": invalid mode \"-rw-rw-rw-\" for /quickstart.sh"***

-rw-rw-rw seems about right to me. What am I missing?

This is in my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
COPY quickstart.sh /
CMD ["\/quickstart.sh"]
```

And this is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image', '.' ]

    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'myservice'
      - '--image'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
      - '--region'
      - 'europe-north1'
      - '--platform'
      - 'managed'
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
images: 
     - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

Comment: Did you try by any chance to use icalcs or CALCS for the permission so you take ownership?

Comment: @StefanNeacsu Yes I’ve used ”icacls /grant Everyone:F” which results in -rw-rw-rw (777).

Comment: After looking again at the error I think it seems it thinks that the file name is the mode which is not the case so by changing to the correct mode would fix the issue.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Morfinismo  No. I ended up removing the Dockerfile and deploying directly to AppEngine instead.

Comment: @StefanNeacsu Well that is essentially what I’m asking. The mode according to the Google Cloud docs should be +x (unix) which is the equivalent of -rw-rw-rw on a Windows system, which I’m on. Still it complains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the Cloud Build environment sandbox your `quickstart.sh` does not have execution permissions, which you can check adding this step to your Cloud Build `cloudbuild.yaml` config file:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
        ls -lart
```

I am not sure if the Cloud Build sandbox will allow you to give execution permissions to a bash script but you might try to do it by adding another step with `chmod +x quickstart.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem a few hours ago, I fixed it by adding an **exec form** `ENTRYPOINT` to the **end** of the `Dockerfile`.

I tried the **shell form** `ENTRYPOINT`, but it didn't work, presumably because of the following:

> **The shell form prevents any `CMD` or `run` command line arguments from being used**, but has the disadvantage that your `ENTRYPOINT` will be started as a subcommand of `/bin/sh -c`, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable will not be the container’s `PID 1` - and will *not* receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a `SIGTERM` from `docker stop <container>`.

GCP probably needs to pass some command line arguments.

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)